# Cannot invoke 'enumerateObjects' with an argument list of type '((AnyObject!, NSInteger, UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) -> ())'

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3

I am getting below error in my project at this line in Xcode 8 while it works fine in Xcode 7.

```
(self.columnHeights[section] as AnyObject).enumerateObjects({(object : AnyObject!, idx : NSInteger,pointer :UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>)
```

Error

```
 Cannot invoke 'enumerateObjects' with an argument list of type '((AnyObject!, NSInteger, UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) -> ())'
```

Please advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Swift 3 most of the `AnyObject` types have been changed to `Any`

```
(self.columnHeights[section] as AnyObject).enumerateObjects({(object : Any, idx : Int, pointer :UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>)
```

As always I'd recommend to use native Swift `Array` rather than Foundation `NSArray` to take advantage of the specific type information.